# Did salesforce change the UI for all the information pages?

Tags: apex

When I used to look up in google for the 'list methods' or 'map methods', i used to be directed to a page with neatly laid out table which used to show all the methods available, their return types, arguments etc. Now when I do the search I am redirected to the page which shows all the methods then one has to click on each of those methods to gather more details. This effects when the we have to find details about the describesObject etc.

The only option is to look up these methods on database.com pages which are still the old ones(luckily). Any other place I can find old pages?

**EDIT**
For those who still love the old view, you can download the summer'13 apex pdf doc http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode280/salesforce_apex_language_reference.pdf

Answer (score 1):

They have changed all the reference for apex code, now you first need to click on Class Type then it method and then you will be able to view its argument and return type. This is bit irritating and consumes time but its look like java doc references. The only way is database.com reference but these references may be updated soon. Unfortunately those urls are same as previous urls where were all details on same page.

Temporarily you can  use Google web cached page e.g; http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:-uXlbmr0EJUJ:www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk